# How can I join these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a number of devices logging different data at different times and want to get all the data in a single query, ordered by time.  An example of the kinds of tables I have:

```
CREATE TABLE location(
    device_id INT, -- REFERENCES device(id)
    timestamp DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    position GEOMETRY NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE temperature(
    device_id INT, -- REFERENCES device(id)
    timestamp DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    temp FLOAT NOT NULL
)
```

I want to have a single query that joins the tables on device_id and timestamp that contains nulls when the timestamps don't match.  An example of the output format I am seeking is:

```
device_id, timestamp, location, temperature
1, 2011/12/1 10:00:00, (35.1, 139.2), NULL
1, 2011/12/1 10:00:01, NULL, 9.0
1, 2011/12/1 10:00:02, (35.1, 139.2), 9.1
```

I've tried doing FULL JOIN but cannot figure out how to do the timestamp column without a huge CASE statement (keep in mind although I've only shown 2 tables, this can have many more).

```
SELECT 
    location.device_id, 
    CASE WHEN location.timestamp IS NOT NULL THEN
        location.timestamp
    ELSE 
        temperature.timestamp 
    END as timestamp, 
    location,
    temp
FROM
    location 
    FULL JOIN temperature ON location.device_id = temperature.device_id 
        AND location.timestamp = temperature.timestamp
ORDER BY
    timestamp
```

Is there a simpler way to write this kind of query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) expression.

```
SELECT 
    location.device_id, 
    COALESCE(location.timestamp, temperature.timestamp) as timestamp, 
    position,
    temp
FROM
    location 
    FULL JOIN temperature ON location.device_id = temperature.device_id 
        AND location.timestamp = temperature.timestamp
ORDER BY
    timestamp;
```

Comment: Using the coalesce operator does the job.
The isnull() operator will do the same, but only accepts 2 parameters, while the coalesce accepts many.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an OUTER Join to the temperature table.  That will return nulls in the case where there is no matching row in the temperature table.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `COALESCE` to get the device_id/timestamp, as follows:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(l.device_id, t.device_id) as device_id,
    COALESCE(l.timestamp, t.timestamp) as timestamp,
    l.position as location,
    t.temp as temperature
FROM location l
FULL JOIN temperature t ON l.device_id = t.device_id 
    AND l.timestamp = t.timestamp
ORDER BY 2
```

Also note the increased readability by aliasing the tables with very short names (l and t).

You may want to review your ordering - perhaps you want `ORDER BY 1, 2` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT device_id, timestamp, position, NULL AS temp
  FROM location
UNION ALL
SELECT device_id, timestamp, NULL AS position, temp
  FROM temperature
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp;
```

Note the `ALL` keyword is required here.